# A domain error occurred in SQL Server 2000 while updating the data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have created a function like the one below

```
ALTER  FUNCTION fn_Calc
(@Lat1  Float,
 @Lng1  Float,
 @Lat2  Float,
 @Lng2  Float)
RETURNS Float
AS
BEGIN

Declare @x      as Float
Declare @y      as Float
Declare @Distance   as Float

Select  @x = (SIN(RADIANS(@Lat1)) * SIN(RADIANS(@Lat2)) + COS(RADIANS(@Lat1)) * COS(RADIANS(@Lat2)) * COS(ABS((RADIANS(@Lng2)) - (RADIANS(@Lng1)))))
Select  @y = ATAN((SQRT(1-(POWER(@x,2))) / @x))

Select  @Distance = (1.852 * 60.0 * ((@y / PI()) * 180)) / 1.609344

RETURN  @Distance

END
```

I am using the above function to update a column in a table like below:

```
Update test 
set calc = dbo.fn_Calc(cast(Lat as float), cast(Long as float), dblLat, dblLong)
```

While running the above query I got the error.

> "A domain error occured."

What can be causing this error?

Comment: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/domain-error-occurred/

Comment: Please, specify the parameter values, what you pass into function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fn_Calc 
(
      @Lat1 FLOAT
    , @Lng1 FLOAT
    , @Lat2 FLOAT
    , @Lng2 FLOAT
)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE 
          @x FLOAT
        , @y FLOAT

    SELECT @x = 
                  SIN(RADIANS(@Lat1))
                * SIN(RADIANS(@Lat2)) + COS(RADIANS(@Lat1))
                * COS(RADIANS(@Lat2))
                * COS(ABS(RADIANS(@Lng2) - RADIANS(@Lng1)))

    SELECT @y = ATAN(SQRT(ABS(1 - POWER(@x, 2))) / @x)

    RETURN (111.12 * ((@y / PI()) * 180)) / 1.609344

END
```

Comment: Hi Devart, i think its working for me. i need to do some more testing to compare the values. Can you please let me know what could be the reason of getting the error. I Really appreciate your help. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Roshan your version might attempt to perform a square root on a negative number, which SQL Server can't do (try `SELECT SQRT(-1)` - you get a different error message but `ABS()` will fix that).

Comment: @AaronBertrand the above update by "Devart" is working fine for me. What could be the reason of using (111.12) instead of (1.852 * 60.0) both are same in the value.

Comment: You'll have to ask @DevArt, though I don't believe that is the change that fixed this, and he just grabbed this function from elsewhere rather than "fixing" yours. Where did you get yours, btw? Did you notice the link points out certain operations can fail with the error you're getting due to feeding them negative numbers? And did you notice the more substantial change in the answer is that it added an `ABS()` which prevents negative numbers?

Comment: In your case, as mentioned @AaronBertrand, the error was that the square root can't be taken of a negative number. Although, really, the square root can be  taken of a negative number, but not with T-SQL (look towards complex numbers). The way the constant 111.12 is written doesn't affect the code. It is just my habit to write like this. I'm glad to be of assistance.

Comment: The function created early one year back, and it is working fine. Yesturday morning i have updated the old table with new table. both are same in the structure includeing the data type. I know that could not be the reason. But still it was workin fine. Even i was surprised what could be the reason of this. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome @Roshan. If this suggestion suits you, I would appreciate if you could confirm it.